# Can't find the user login page

Tags: php, nginx, zend-framework

Trying to run a Zend application I get a 404 on the application document root request.

This 404 is the one rendered by the `/Application/view/errors/404.php` page of the Zend framework, not the server 404 page.

I installed Nginx and php-fpm as well as MariaDB on my Linux box to run this Zend application.

I'm attaching the php execution to the PHP Eclipse XDebug debugger which shows the index.php page being run, down to its `Zend\Mvc\Application::init` call.

```
// Setup autoloading
require 'init_autoloader.php';

// Run the application!
Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require 'config/application.config.php')->run();
```

I have configured the Nginx virtual host:

```
$ cat programs/install/nginx/conf/sites-available/nginx-dev.extrapack.my-group.com 
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name dev.extrapack.my-group.com;
  root   /home/stephane/dev/php/projects/my/Extrapack-Mon/public;
  index index.php;
  include /home/stephane/programs/install/nginx/conf/security;

  access_log  /home/stephane/programs/install/nginx/logs/access.log;
  error_log  /home/stephane/programs/install/nginx/logs/error.log notice;

  location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt)$ {
    access_log        off;
    log_not_found     off;
    expires           max;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri = 404;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass php5-fpm-sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS 'on'; # Make PHP-FPM aware that this vhost is HTTPs enabled
    fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV development;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
  }

  client_max_body_size 20m;
  client_body_buffer_size 128k;
}
```

The `/Application/config/module.config.php` file contains:

```
    'application' => array(
        'type'    => 'Literal',
        'options' => array(
            'route'    => '/application',
            'defaults' => array(
                '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                'controller'    => 'Index',
                'action'        => 'index',
            ),
        ),
```

But the `IndexController` is not being hit at all, the debugger doesn't stop at any of the breakpoints in the controller.

I added this code chunk in the `onBootstrap` callback:

```
$em->attach('dispatch.error', function($e){
    switch ($e->getError()) {
        case 'error-router-no-match':
            break;
    }
}, -100);
```

and the debugger does stop at the breakpoint on the `break;` line, meaning the error is a `error-router-no-match` one.

Here is the url the debugger is requesting whenI run the debug configuration:
`http://dev.extrapack.group.com/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=ECLIPSE_DBGP&KEY=14776859837352`

As a Zend noob I don't know what else I could provide you with to help but if some piece of configuration is missing in my question, I'd be glad to add it.

I'm on Zend version 2.4.9.

EDIT: I added an SSL virtual host which enables the application to finally display its user login page, solving the issue.

```
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name dev.extrapack.group.com;
  root /home/stephane/dev/php/projects/Extrapack-Mon/public;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /home/stephane/programs/install/nginx/conf/sites-available/extrapack.group.com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /home/stephane/programs/install/nginx/conf/sites-available/extrapack.group.com.key;

  location /simplesaml {
    index index.php;
    alias /usr/share/simplesaml/www;
    location ~ ^/simplesaml/(module\.php)(/.+)$ {
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_pass php5-fpm-sock;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^/simplesaml/(module\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/simplesaml/www/$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_pass php5-fpm-sock;
    }
  }

  location / {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass php5-fpm-sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
    try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS 'on'; # Make PHP-FPM aware that this vhost is HTTPs enabled
    fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV development;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have solved the issue by adding an SSL virtual host. But I must admit I still do not know what was wrong with my non SSL configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Your url should mapped as http://dev.extrapack.group.com as default path on your http server, not http://dev.extrapack.group.com/index.php.